# Optimize Constrained L1 Objective

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, constraints

I am looking to see if it possible to optimize the following objective:

Minimize $(\| Ax - b \|_1) + (\| Ax - c \|_1)$ wrt to $x$ such that $\| x \|_1 = 1$ and all elements of $x$ are nonnegative. $A$ is a matrix, and $x$, $b$, and $c$ are column vectors. $\|\cdot\|_1$ is the L1 norm.

I have been reading about alternating direction method of multipliers (ADMM), but am not sure if this is the same setting. In particular, not sure if the constrained objective is convex or how to incorporate the nonnegative constraint. One technique could be to substitute $x$ with element-wise abs($x$) to enforce the nonegative constraint, but then is the resulting objective convex?

Any approach would be appreciated -- gradient method, alternating method, closed form solution, etc.
Thank you.

Comment: More context is needed here. Is there any particular reason why you are squaring the two terms in the cost to minimize?

Comment: Just interested in this particular form, has interpretation as finding a midpoint/centroid. If you have an approach without the squares, would also be appreciated.

Comment: If you remove the squares then you will get a linear programming problem which be easily solved.

Comment: How can without the squares be cast as a linear program? Thank you

Comment: I've amended the question so the non-squares version can be an answer.

Comment: The book Convex Optimization by Boyd and Vandenberghe is one place to learn about how to express this type of problem (without the squares) as a linear program.

Comment: So I looked into that. I don't see a way to capture $\| x \|_1 = 1$ with a linear program. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Due to $x \ge 0$, $\|x\|_1 = \sum_i x_i = 1$ is a convex constraint.